# List-initialization and failed overload resolution of initializer_list constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, overload-resolution, list-initialization

The below fails to compile with `clang35 -std=c++11`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <initializer_list>

class A
{
 public:
  A(int, bool) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
  A(int, double) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
  A(std::initializer_list<int>) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
  A a1 = {1, 1.0};
  return 0;
}
```

with error

```
init.cpp:15:14: error: type 'double' cannot be narrowed to 'int' in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]
  A a1 = {1, 1.0};
             ^~~
init.cpp:15:14: note: insert an explicit cast to silence this issue
  A a1 = {1, 1.0};
             ^~~
             static_cast<int>( )
```

OTOH, it warns about the narrowing and compiles on `g++48 -std=c++11`

```
init.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
init.cpp:15:17: warning: narrowing conversion of ‘1.0e+0’ from ‘double’ to ‘int’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
   A a1 = {1, 1.0};
                 ^
init.cpp:15:17: warning: narrowing conversion of ‘1.0e+0’ from ‘double’ to ‘int’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
```

and produces the result

```
A::A(std::initializer_list<int>)
```

Does either behaviour make sense? Quoting from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)

> All constructors that take std::initializer_list as the only argument,
>   or as the first argument if the remaining arguments have default
>   values, are examined, and matched by overload resolution against a
>   single argument of type std::initializer_list
>
> If the previous stage does not produce a match, all constructors of T
>   participate in overload resolution against the set of arguments that
>   consists of the elements of the braced-init-list, with the restriction
>   that only non-narrowing conversions are allowed. If this stage
>   produces an explicit constructor as the best match for a
>   copy-list-initialization, compilation fails (note, in simple
>   copy-initialization, explicit constructors are not considered at all)

Since narrowing conversions aren't allowed, I would expect the overload resolution step to not match the `A(std::initializer_list<int>)` constructor and instead match the `A(int, double)` one. For example, changing `A(std::initializer_list<int>)` to `A(std::initializer_list<std::string>)` compiles with both `clang35` and `g++48` and prints

```
A::A(int, double)
```

as expected.

Comment: Presumably you mean Clang 3.5. What you named the binary isn't really helpful :) `mv clang25 clang35` "oops"

Comment: You are right :) This is the versioning convention used by the team maintaining build systems at work and I never gave it a second thought.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The behavior makes sense. Scott Meyers has an example almost exactly like this in Effective Modern C++ (emphasis in original):

> If, however, one or more constructors declare a parameter of type `std::initializer_list`, calls using the braced initialization syntax strongly prefer the overloads taking `std;:initializer_list`s. *Strongly*. If there's *any way* for compilers to construe a call using a braced initializer to be a constructor taking a `std::initializer_list`, compilers will employ that interpretation.

Example using this class:

```
class Widget {
public:
    Widget(int, bool);
    Widget(int, double);
    Widget(std::initializer_list<long double>);
};

Widget w1(10, true); // calls first ctor
Widget w2{10, true}; // calls std::initializer_list ctor
Widget w3(10, 5.0); // calls second ctor
Widget w4{10, 5.0}; // calls std::initializer_list ctor
```

Those two calls call the `initializer_list` ctor even though they involve converting BOTH arguments - and even though the other constructors are perfect matches.

Furthermore:

> Compilers' determination to match braced initializers with constructors taking `std::initializer_list`s is so strong, it prevails even if the best-match `std::initializer_list` constructor can't be called. For example:
>
> ```
> class Widget {
> public:
>     Widget(int, bool); // as before
>     Widget(int, double); // as before
>     Widget(std::initializer_list<bool> ); // now bool
> };
>
> Widget w{10, 5.0}; // error! requires narrowing conversions
> ```

Both compilers pick the correct overload (the `initializer_list` one) - which we can see is required from the standard (§13.3.1.7):

> When objects of non-aggregate class type `T` are list-initialized (8.5.4), overload resolution selects the constructor
>   in two phases:
>
> (1.1) — Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list constructors (8.5.4) of the class `T` and the
>   argument list consists of the initializer list as a single argument.
>   (1.2) — If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again, where the
>   candidate functions are all the constructors of the class `T` and the argument list consists of the elements
>   of the initializer list.

But calling that particular constructor involves a narrowing. In 8.5.1:

> If the *initializer-clause* is an expression
>   and a narrowing conversion (8.5.4) is required to convert the expression, the program is ill-formed.

So the program is ill-formed. In this case, clang chooses to throw an error while gcc chooses to issue a warning. Both compilers are conforming.

Comment: Which behaviour makes sense? clang and gcc disagree - clang 3.5 fails to compile, while g++ 4.8.3 picks the `initializer_list` overload even in the presence of a narrowing conversion. The example above doesn't illustrate any of the difficulties - the conversions aren't narrowing and hence the `initilalizer_list` overload being picked isn't surprising.

Comment: We might add that this _strong preference_ is awesome because then you can e.g. `std::vector<std::string> { "hello", "world" }` because the compiler _makes the effort_ to try and see the initializer list as initializers for objects of type `std::string`. Otherwise we would be stuck forever writing `std::vector<std::string> { std::string{"hello"}, std::string{"world"} }`. _And imagine the pain when you tried to initiailize something [less trivial](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28036210)_.

Comment: @Pradhan adding narrowing example from the book

Comment: @Barry Both compilers are conforming. Narrowing makes the program *ill-formed*, which only means that the compiler must issue a diagnostic; GCC's warning satisfies this requirement.

Comment: @T.C. I see lots of examples that explicitly say `// error: narrowing`

Comment: @Barry Examples are not normative, and in any event the standard does not distinguish between errors and warnings. Both are diagnostic messages.

Comment: @Barry Thanks for the answer. I think the emphasis should be on the last part of your answer since the rest of it is summarized(not in as much detail of course) in the question. The crucial point seems to be that overload resolution picks the `initializer_list<X>` constructor if there is a conversion from the elements of the `braced-init-list` to `X`. However, this is *ill-formed* if any of these conversions are narrowing.

Comment: @T.C.: A "diagnostic" is whatever the implementation says is a diagnostic (but without the proper documentation, neither an error nor warning message technically qualifies). A compiler can also require specific flags to conform, such as one to treat some or all warnings as errors.

Comment: Since gcc 5.1 its  an error now. The interesting thing is that gcc will not issue this warning for `X x5{0,10.5};` or `X x5{1,10.5};`, it looks like it finds 0 and 1 , and since it can be easily converted to false and true, it does not look further.