# Why is this initializer_list constructor a viable overload?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, overload-resolution, list-initialization

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <initializer_list>

class A
{
 public:
  A(int, bool) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
  A(int, double) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
  A(std::initializer_list<int>) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
  A a1 = {1, 1.0};
  return 0;
}
```

(This question is a follow-up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28058371/list-initialization-and-failed-overload-resolution-of-initializer-list-construct).)

The above program fails to compile with `clang35 -std=c++11`

```
init.cpp:15:14: error: type 'double' cannot be narrowed to 'int' in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]
  A a1 = {1, 1.0};
             ^~~
init.cpp:15:14: note: insert an explicit cast to silence this issue
  A a1 = {1, 1.0};
             ^~~
             static_cast<int>( )
```

while `g++48 -std=c++11` chooses a produce a warning to diagnose the ill-formed narrowing

```
init.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
init.cpp:15:17: warning: narrowing conversion of ‘1.0e+0’ from ‘double’ to ‘int’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
   A a1 = {1, 1.0};
                 ^
init.cpp:15:17: warning: narrowing conversion of ‘1.0e+0’ from ‘double’ to ‘int’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
```

and produces the result

```
A::A(std::initializer_list<int>)
```

My question is if `A::A(std::initializer_list<int>)` should be a viable overload. Below are standard quotes that I think imply that the `initializer_list` overload should not be viable.

From `13.3.2 [over.match.viable]`

> Second, for `F` to be a viable function, there shall exist for each
>   argument an *implicit conversion* sequence that converts that argument
>   to the corresponding parameter of `F`.

From `4 [conv]`

> An expression `e` can be *implicitly converted* to a type `T` if and
>   only if the declaration `T t=e`; is well-formed, for some invented
>   temporary variable `t`.

From `8.5.1 [dcl.init.aggr]`

> If the *initializer-clause* is an expression and a narrowing
>   conversion is required to convert the expression, the program is
>   ill-formed.

Using `8.5.1` and `4`, since the following is not well-formed

```
std::initializer_list<int> e = {1, 1.0};
```

`{1, 1.0}` is not *implicitly convertible* to `std::initializer_list<int>`.

Using the quote from `13.3.2`, shouldn't it imply that `A::A(std::initializer_list<int>)` isn't a viable function when doing overload resolution for `A a1 = {1, 1.0};`? Finding no viable `initializer_list` constructors, shouldn't this statement pick `A::A(int, double)`?

Comment: How does 8.5.1 apply for `int t = 1.0;`? That's not aggregate initialization, is it?

Comment: It was stated in the post that you linked to that constructors that take an initializer list are strongly favored.  So the compiler picks the initializer list constructor and then tries to convert and since it narrows the compilation fails.

Comment: @Columbo Sorry, I didn't get your point. Also, for `8.5.1`, I didn't paste the entire standard quote, but since you mention aggregate initialization, I guess that is clear enough.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, but "strong preference" is Scott Meyers putting the standard in simple English. I am asking how it follows from the standardese.

Comment: @Pradhan I posted an answer to make my point more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that the problem in your analysis is the fact that the statement

```
int t = 1.0;
```

is indeed well-formed - an implicit conversion from `double` to `int` obviously exists. [over.ics.list]/4 also describes it:

> Otherwise, if the parameter type is `std::initializer_list<X>` and all
>   the elements of the initializer list can be implicitly converted to
>   `X`, the implicit conversion sequence is the worst conversion
>   necessary to convert an element of the list to `X`, or if the
>   initializer list has no elements, the identity conversion.

Every element from the initializer list can be implicitly converted to `int`, thus the constructor is viable and chosen. However, only once it is chosen, the whole thing hard-errors, [dcl.init.list]/(3.6):

> The applicable constructors are enumerated and the best one is chosen
>   through overload resolution (13.3, 13.3.1.7). **If a narrowing
>   conversion (see below) is required to convert any of the arguments,
>   the program is ill-formed.**

As you can see, the constructor to call is determined before the narrowing-check is performed. In other words, **the viability of an initializer-list constructor is not depending on narrowing of any arguments.**
Thus the code should be ill-formed.

One way to get the desired behavior is to use a constructor template with SFINAE

```
template <typename T, typename=std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<int, T>{}>>
A(std::initializer_list<T>) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db85f5e7c6a78783).

Comment: Ah ok, that seems to explain it. Going over those parts to ensure I understand. What do you think is the standard specifies it in this seemingly convoluted way? Why not simply ensure that in it isn't a viable overload? Is it to avoid complicating aggregate initialization? IOW they would have to differentiate between `<some pod> = {1, 1.0}` and `<some init_list> = {1, 1.0}`?

Comment: @Pradhan I have no idea tbh. It seems that either we're missing some corner-cases or the section is defected.

Comment: I think it would be strange if the constructor used was dependend on the value of the argument (for conversions from integer to integer type, where the source is a constant expression, for example).